# What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a one-line snippet that works perfectly in the command line, but fails and throws up errors when I run it as part of a batch script.

The below commands behaves as expected, deleting all empty subfolders in the folder.

```
for /f "delims=" %d in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%d"
```

However, when put in a batch file like so...

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%d"
```

...it throws the standard error:

> Sort is not recognised as an internal or external command

I've been experimenting for the last hour or so with and without escaping the pipe, changing the order of the options, looking up the documentation of both `dir` and `sort`, etc., but I've still not been able to figure out what's going on here. The rest of the batch file, which is only a few lines, works fine, and this is the only line in it that fails.

Comment: I guess your `PATH` variable is not set properly, or you are overwriting it elsewhere in the script, so the command interpreter does no longer know where to search `sort.exe`; the other commands are `cmd`-internal ones, so they are all found...

Comment: Damnit. I'd completely forgotten `path` was an environment variable. You're right, I defined a variable in the script called path. Can I ask how you knew it was `PATH` that was being overwritten? I'd never have made the connection from `sort` to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: It was the error message together with the fact that `sort` is the only external command in your command line that led me to that suspicion...

Comment: "sort is not recognized as an internal or external command..." - We know that it's not an internal command, but we expect it to be recognized as an external command. External commands are on the PATH. If it can't be found, it's because it's not on the PATH. So maybe you messed up the PATH.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks to you all. Tested and script is now working perfectly.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### A) How does Windows command processor search for commands?

Windows command processor searches for a *COMMAND* to execute which

1. is not an internal command of `cmd.exe` **and**
2. is just specified with file name without file extension and without path

for a file matching the pattern `command.*` **and** having a file extension listed in local environment variable `PATHEXT`

1. first in current directory **and**
2. next in all directories of local environment variable `PATH`.

**SORT** and **FIND** and **FINDSTR** and **ROBOCOPY** and **XCOPY** and many more commands are not internal commands of `cmd.exe`. They are console applications installed with Windows located in directory `%SystemRoot%\System32` having the file name `sort.exe`, `find.exe`, `findstr.exe`, `robocopy.exe`, `xcopy.exe`, ...

Such console applications available by default on Windows are called **external commands** to distinguish them better from console applications not installed with Windows operating system.

---

### B) How is the environment variable PATH defined?

There are three types of `PATH` variables:

1. **System** `PATH` which is used for all accounts and stored in Windows registry under key:

   ```
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
   ```
2. **User** `PATH` which is used only for current account and stored in Windows registry under key:

   ```
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
   ```
3. **Local** `PATH` which is always a **copy** of the local `PATH` of parent process which started the current process.

Windows concatenates **system** and **user** `PATH` to **local** `PATH` for the Windows Explorer instance used as Windows desktop with the shortcuts on the desktop screen and the Windows start menu and the Windows taskbar as visible interface for the user called [Windows shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell) from which users usually start programs.

The entire currently active environment variables list of running process is copied for the new process by Windows on starting a new process. The Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) does this environment variables list copy from the memory of the current process to the memory of the new process on function parameter `lpEnvironment` (long pointer to environment) being a null pointer. One of the `CreateProcess` functions is always used on Windows on starting an executable from another executable.

The parent process cannot modify the environment variables of any child process nor can a child process modify the environment variables of its parent process.

This means once a process like `cmd.exe` was started for execution of a batch file, the process has its own set of environment variables which only the process itself can modify. No other process can modify the environment variables of an already running process.

---

### C) What does the error message mean?

The error message

> '...' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

always means that

1. the file name of a

   - console application
   - GUI application
   - script (batch file, PowerShell script, Perl script, VBScript, JScript, ...)

   was specified for execution most likely without file extension and without (complete) path to the executable/script file **and**
2. Windows failed to find a file matching the pattern `FileName.*` with a file extension listed in currently active environment variable `PATHEXT` in current directory or any other directory in currently active environment variable `PATH`.

---

### D) What are the possible reasons for this error message?

Typical reasons are:

##### 1. The file name of the file to execute was specified wrong due to a typing mistake.

Check character by character the name of the command/executable.

##### 2. The current directory is different to the directory containing the file to execute.

Run `echo Current directory is: %CD%` on command line or add this line to the batch file above the command line which fails to see what the current directory is.

##### 3. The executable or script to run is not installed at all.

Verify the existence of the executable to run. Some installation packages work only if other packages like Java, NPM, PHP, etc. were installed before.

##### 4. The directory of the file to execute is not in `PATH` at all.

Open in Windows **Control Panel** the **System** settings window, click on **Advanced system settings** on left side, click on button **Environment Variables** and look in both lists for `Path` and their values. By default `Path` exists only in list of **System variables**.

##### 5. A running process/application was not restarted after modification of system or user `PATH`.

A modification of **system** `PATH` or **user** `PATH` with command `setx` or via **Control Panel – System and Security – System – Advanced system settings - Environment Variables** was made by the user or an installer, but an already running process/application like an opened command prompt or PowerShell window was not closed/exited and opened/restarted after `PATH` modification. This is necessary as described in detail in chapter **F)** below.

##### 6. An executable in `%SystemRoot%\System32` is not found on 64-bit Windows.

There is the directory `%SystemRoot%\System32` with 64-bit executables and `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` with 32-bit executables on 64-bit Windows with a processor supporting also the x86 instruction set. Most executables exist in both directories. But there are some executables existing only in `System32` and a few only in `SysWOW64`.

The **system** `PATH` contains by default as first folder path `%SystemRoot%\System32`. But which one of the two Windows system folders is searched for the executable specified without path or with the path `%SystemRoot%\System32` depends on the execution environment. An application or script executed in 64-bit environment is really accessing `%SystemRoot%\System32` while an application or script executed in 32-bit environment is redirected by the Windows [file system redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) to the directory `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64`.

An application or script running in 32-bit environment which wants to run a 64-bit executable in `%SystemRoot%\System32` has to use the fully qualified file name of the executable with file path `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative`.

**Note:** `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative` is neither a directory nor any type of link. It is something very special existing only for x86 applications. It does not exist for amd64 applications. The condition `if exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative` in a batch file is always false in both environments, but `if exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\cmd.exe` is true in 32-bit execution environment and false in 64-bit environment and also on 32-bit Windows. This condition can be used in batch scripts to find out if the batch file is processed by 32-bit `cmd.exe` in `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` on 64-bit Windows which can be important to know depending on the task.

See also the Microsoft documentations [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details) and [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys).

##### 7. `PATH` contains a reference to a not (yet) defined environment variable.

It is possible to specify in `PATH` a folder path using a reference to value of another environment variable like `SystemRoot`. It is important that this environment variable is also defined in same set of environment variables or a set of environment variables processed first by Windows.

For example if `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` is added to **system** `PATH` environment variable, there must be defined also a **system** environment variable `JAVA_HOME` with the base folder path to Java program files. It is not enough to have defined a **user** environment variable `JAVA_HOME` or define the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` later in the **local** environment of a batch file.

`%JAVA_HOME%\bin` added to **user** `PATH` is expanded by Windows to a full qualified folder path if the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` is defined either as **system** or as **user** environment variable, but not on `JAVA_HOME` defined later in the **local** environment of a Windows command process.

Such a mistake can be seen easily by opening a new [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window after making a modification on **system** or **user** `PATH` from Windows start menu and running `set path`. The output `PATH` should not contain anymore any `%Variable%` environment variable value reference.

##### 8. The LOCAL variable `PATH` was modified before on command line or in batch file.

Run `set path` on command line or add this command to the batch file above the command line which fails to see the current values of the environment variables `PATH` and `PATHEXT`.

That reason is responsible for external command **SORT** not being found on execution of the batch file which contains somewhere above `set path=...`.

##### 9. LOCAL variable `PATH` is too long.

The **local** variable `PATH` of `cmd.exe` is too long. The Windows Command Processor fails to find any executable/script in the folder paths of **local** `Path` if the string value is longer than `8191` characters.

Please see [my second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75050498/3074564) here for more details regarding to length limitations of `PATH`.

Thanks goes to [Albert Mosiałek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4926013/) for informing me about this cause of a not recognized program or script.

---

### E) How to avoid this error message?

Best is coding a batch file for being independent on `PATH` and `PATHEXT` and the order of directories in `PATH` which means here using the command line:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\sort.exe /r') do rd "%%d"
```

Any **external command** of which executable is stored in `%SystemRoot%\System32` should be specified in a batch file with this path and with file extension `.exe`. Then Windows command interpreter does not need to search for a file using **local** `PATH` and `PATHEXT` and the batch file works always (as long as environment variable `SystemRoot` is not also modified in the batch file which I have never seen).

---

### F) When is a system or user PATH change applied to processes?

When a user opens a command prompt window via Windows start menu or from within a Windows Explorer window, the user starts `cmd.exe` with implicit using option `/K` to keep the console window open after finishing a command which is good for debugging a batch file.

When a batch file is doubled clicked in Windows Explorer, the user starts `cmd.exe` for processing the batch file with implicit using option `/C` to close the console window after finishing batch processing which is not good for debugging a batch file as error messages cannot be seen in this case.

In both cases Windows creates a copy of the environment variables of the application starting `cmd.exe` which is usually Windows Explorer. Therefore the started command process has a **local** `PATH` of which value is the same as the parent process had on starting `cmd.exe`.

Example:

1. Open a command prompt window, run `title Process1` and run `set path`.
   Output is `PATH` and `PATHEXT` as currently defined for current user account in the console window having now the window title *Process1*.
2. Run `set PATH=%SystemRoot%\System32` and next once again `set path`.
   Output is again `PATH` and `PATHEXT`, but with `PATH` containing only one directory now.
3. Run `start "Process2"` and run in new console window with window title *Process2* the command `set path`.
   Output is `PATH` and `PATHEXT` with same values as before in *Process1*.
   This demonstrates that on starting a new process the **current** environment variables of running process are copied and not what Windows itself has currently stored in Windows registry.
4. Run in *Process2* the command `set PATH=` and next `set path`.
   Output is only `PATHEXT` because **local** `PATH` does not exist anymore for *Process2*.
   This demonstrates that every process can modify its environment variables including complete deletion.
5. Switch to *Process1* window, run the command `set PATH=%PATH%;%SystemRoot%` and next `set path`.
   Output is `PATH` with two directories and `PATHEXT`.
6. Run the command `start "Process3"` and in opened window with title *Process3* the command `set path`.
   Output is `PATH` with two directories as defined also for *Process1* and `PATHEXT`.
7. Run in *Process3* the command `set PATH=%SystemRoot%\System32`.

There are 3 command processes running with following values for **local** `PATH` when `%SystemRoot%` expands to `C:\Windows`:

*Process1*: `PATH=C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows`
*Process2*: `PATH` does not exist at all.
*Process3*: `PATH=C:\Windows\System32`

So what happens now on opening **Control Panel – System – Advanced System Settings – Environment Variables** and adding to list of **User variables** the **new** environment variable `PATH` with value `C:\Temp`, or in case of there is already a **user** `PATH` environment variable, **edit** `PATH` and append `;C:\Temp` to the value?

Well, as long as the dialog window with title **Environment Variables** showing the two lists is opened, nothing happens on modifying the variables, until button **OK** is clicked to take over all changes into Windows registry and close the window.

Let's go back to the three running command processes and run in *Process1*, *Process2* and *Process3* the command `set path`. It can be seen:

*Process1*: `PATH=C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows`
*Process2*: `PATH` does not exist at all.
*Process3*: `PATH=C:\Windows\System32`

Nothing changed on already running processes.

**No process can modify the environment variables of a different running process!**

Open from Windows start menu one more command prompt window and run in fourth command process the command `set path`. It can be seen that **local** `PATH` of fourth command process has appended the directory `C:\Temp` now.

Then close all four command processes and delete the added **user** `PATH` respectively remove `;C:\Temp` from **user** `PATH` if having appended this directory path before.

How is this possible if no process can modify the environment variables of an already running process?

How was the environment variables list of Windows Explorer instance running as Windows desktop modified on closing **Environment Variables** window with button **OK**?

The answer on those two questions was given by [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) in his comment.

After writing the modifications on **system**  and **user** variables into registry on clicking button **OK** of **Environment Variables** window, Windows sends the [WM_SETTINGCHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-settingchange) message to all top-level windows to inform the running applications about changed system parameters.

It is up to the application if this event message is handled at all and how. Windows Explorer running as Windows desktop reads the environment variables from registry and updates its environment variables list accordingly. Other applications like Total Commander handle this message also and update their lists of environment variables too. But `cmd.exe` does not do that fortunately as this would be really problematic.

Is there any possibility to modify a **system** or **user** variable with notification via `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` from within a command prompt window or batch file?

It is possible to modify the registry value of an environment variable using `reg add` command. But this does not result in sending `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message to all top-level windows. Such changes done with `reg add` or with `regedit` require a restart of Windows (or at least a log off and log on of current user) to be taken into account at all.

But there is also the command `setx` which is designed for modifying a **system** or **user** variable and which also sends the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message to all top-level windows after registry was updated according to specified arguments. Run `setx /?` in a command prompt window for details. But please take into account that `setx` does not modify the **local** environment variable of running command process. This must be done with using command `set` used in addition to `setx`.

---

### G) How is environment variable PATHEXT handled by Windows?

The environment variable `PATHEXT` with the list of file extensions is handled by Windows different in comparison to environment variable `PATH`.

**System** `PATHEXT` and **user** `PATHEXT` are **NOT** concatenated to **local** `PATHEXT`.

A **user** `PATHEXT` **replaces** the **system** `PATHEXT` for all processes running under environment of the account having defined a **user** `PATHEXT`.

There is defined only a **system** `PATHEXT` environment variable by default.

---

### H) Is it possible to disable file search in current directory?

Windows command processor searches by default in current directory if file name of a script file or executable is specified on command line or in a batch file without any path which means without a backslash `\` (or a forward slash `/` thanks to auto-correction) in argument string.

But on Windows Vista and later Windows client versions and on Windows Server 2003 and later Windows server versions it is indeed possible to disable searching for a script/executable in current directory specified without at least relative path `.\` by defining the environment variable `NoDefaultCurrentDirectoryInExePath` with any value as written by [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) in his comment below and explained by Microsoft's documentation about function [NeedCurrentDirectoryForExePathA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-needcurrentdirectoryforexepatha).

See [Removing the current working directory from the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50064901/) for more details on usage of this environment variable.

---

### I) How to modify system or user PATH?

The **system** and **user** `PATH` environment variables are modified by a user best using the Windows GUI dialog window **Environment Variables**. This dialog window can be opened as follows:

1. Click on the Windows **Start** menu button.
2. Type on keyboard **environment variables**.
3. There are offered by Windows the two items:
   **Edit the system environment variables**
   **Edit environment variables for your account**
4. Click on one of the two items to open the **Environment Variables** window.

There can be also opened the Windows **Control Panel**. There must be next clicked on **System and Security** with *Category* selected for display option *View by*. Next must be clicked **System**. There must be clicked on left side **Advanced system settings** and next on the button **Environment Variables...**

The **System** window can be opened also by pressing the key combination <kbd>Windows logo key + Pause</kbd> if the keyboard has the key <kbd>Pause</kbd> at all or at least in combination with the key <kbd>Fn</kbd>. See also the Microsoft documentation page [Keyboard shortcuts in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec).

The further user actions are self-explaining for editing either **user** `Path` in upper list on existing at all or **system** `Path` in lower list.

Comment: The environment variables stored in the registry are either `REG_SZ` or  `REG_EXPAND_SZ` types that reference other `%variables%`. Because enumerating a registry key has no set order, Explorer reloads the environment in 4 passes: system `REG_SZ`, system `REG_EXPAND_SZ`, user `REG_SZ`, and user `REG_EXPAND_SZ`. The `PATH` value is almost always a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` type that's defined in terms of dynamic values and `REG_SZ` values. Also, the user's `PATH` gets appended to the system value. It's important to warn that naive use of setx.exe to modify `PATH` will flatten and expand this structure.

Comment: CMD's default behavior is to first search in the current directory. We can have it skip this step by defining the environment variable `NoDefaultCurrentDirectoryInExePath`. Then for security we can add "." explicitly to `PATH` at the end, or at least after system directories. If we don't add it to `PATH`, then running a file in the current directory has to use an explicit relative path such as `.\program.exe`.

Comment: If for some reason you have an executable that's saved without an extension (.exe or any other), then you can run it in CMD by appending ";." to the `PATHEXT` environment variable.

Answer (score 6):

Most probably, you messed around with the `PATH` variable. Perhaps you are overwriting it somewhere else in your script. Since `sort` is an external command, opposed to all the others in your command line like `for`, `dir`, `rd`, which are `cmd`-internal commands, the `PATH` variable is needed to find the command. If `PATH` is not defined, external commands are searched in the current working directory only. There is also a `PATHEXT` variable that is needed to define standard file extensions for executables, like `.com`, `.exe`. So when `sort` appears in command prompt or in a batch file, the system searches the current working directory and all directories specified by the `PATH` variable for a file with the base name `sort` and one of the extensions specified by `PATHEXT`. The command `sort` is actually called `sort.exe` and is usually located in `C:\Windows\System32`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was so sure that I didn't mess with `PATH`. It was that I wasn't aware that `path` and `PATH` are the same. CMD is case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

This answer contains additional information to [my first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) here regarding to length limitations of `PATH`.

There are not good coded executables/scripts which modify **system** or **user** `PATH` without checking first if the folder path to add is not already in string value of one of the two `PATH` environment variables as reported by [Albert Mosiałek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4926013/) in a comment. Multiple executions of such a program results in **local** `PATH` string value of `cmd.exe` becomes longer and longer until reaching the `PATH` length limitations.

The maximum length of **local** `PATH` string value of `cmd.exe` depends on version of Windows and multiple string length limitations.

---

### Length limitations of PATH on Windows Vista and Windows 7

#### Length limitations of system PATH

The **system** `PATH` as stored in Windows registry is truncated to its maximum length of `4095` characters **before** expanding all the environment variable references. The truncated string assigned to **local** `PATH` of `cmd.exe` can be also shorter than `4095` characters on **system** `PATH` contains environment variable references like `%SystemRoot%` (12 characters) expanding to `C:\Windows` (10 characters) and no **user** `PATH` is stored in Windows registry.

The **system** `PATH` is truncated to its maximum length of `4095` characters **after** expansion of the environment variable references. The truncated string assigned to **local** `PATH` of `cmd.exe` can be longer than the string value stored in Windows registry if environment variable references expand to strings which are longer than the environment variable reference strings.

In worst case the **system** `PATH` is truncated twice to a maximum length of `4095` characters, the first time before and the second time after expansion of the environment variable references.

#### Length limitations of user PATH

The **user** `PATH` is ignored completely independent on length of **system** `PATH` if the string value stored in Windows registry is longer than `4095` characters.

The **user** `PATH` is appended with an additional semicolon in expanded form to **local** `PATH` of `cmd.exe` on being in Windows registry not longer than `4095` characters even if the **user** `PATH` is in expanded form longer than `4095` characters because of environment variable references like `%APPDATA%`, `%LOCALAPPDATA%` or `%USERPROFILE%`.

The **local** `PATH` of `cmd.exe` can reach the maximum length of `8191` characters in worst case with a very long and perhaps already once or twice truncated **system** `PATH` and a **user** `PATH` not longer than `4095` characters in Windows registry, but longer than `4095` characters in expanded form.

The Windows Command Processor `cmd.exe` stops finding any executable on **local** `PATH` becomes too long, for example if the **system** `PATH` of 4095 characters in registry expands to a string with 4087 characters and is concatenated with a semicolon and a **user** `Path` stored in Windows registry with 4074 characters, but is expanded to a string value of length 4104 characters, resulting in a **local** `Path` with a total length of `8192` characters. There is not even found anymore any executable in `%SystemRoot%\System32` on **local** `PATH` string value has a length of `8192` characters although the execution of `set path` outputs the **local** `PATH` with first directory path `C:\Windows\System32`.

There is the [Command prompt (Cmd. exe) command-line string limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/command-line-string-limitation) which means that the environment variable name `PATH` plus equal sign `=` plus the variable string value plus the string terminating null byte must fit into a character array of `8192` characters. The string value of the **local** environment variable `PATH` as output on running `set path` in a command prompt window cannot be longer than `8186` characters for that reason although in memory the string value of **local** `Path` can be up to `8191` characters.

The internal command **SET** of `cmd.exe` does not output anymore a line-feed on running `set path` in a command prompt window if the **local** `PATH` has a string value of `8186` or more characters. In the console window is displayed for that reason in this case the environment variable `PATHEXT` with the equal sign and its string value appended to end of the string value of the environment variable `PATH`.

#### Length limitations of Control Panel windows for editing environment variables

A **user** or **system** `PATH` or any other in Windows registry persistent stored environment variable with a string value longer than `4094` characters is not displayed in the **Environment Variables** dialog window. For a user it looks like the environment variable does not exist which has a string value with more than `4094` characters although the environment variable is stored in registry and is perhaps even defined in **local** environment of running processes. The other **user** and **system** variables are still displayed in the **Environment Variables** window.

The **Edit User Variable** and **Edit System Variable** dialog windows display a **Variable value** with up to `4094` characters. A user can delete characters from such a long string value and save the shortened string value. But a user cannot append characters or replace existing characters on string value of the environment variable is longer than `2047` characters. A user can edit for that reason a **user** or **system** environment variable `PATH` with a string value longer than `2047` characters only for removal of a directory path using the **Environment Variables** window of **Control Panel**, but not for changing characters of an existing directory path or adding one more directory path to the environment variable string which is longer than `2047` characters.

#### Recommendations for PATH lengths

The **system** as well as the **user** `PATH` as stored in Windows registry and in their expanded form should be never longer than `4094` characters on Windows Vista and Windows 7 and are best both shorter than `2048` characters to be editable in the **Control Panel** windows.

---

### Length limitations of PATH on Windows XP

#### Length limitations of system PATH

The **system** `PATH` as stored in Windows registry is truncated to its maximum length of `2047` characters **before** expanding all the environment variable references. The truncated string assigned to **local** `PATH` of `cmd.exe` can be also shorter than `2047` characters on **system** `PATH` contains environment variable references like `%SystemRoot%` (12 characters) expanding to `C:\Windows` (10 characters) and no **user** `PATH` is stored in Windows registry.

The **system** `PATH` is truncated to its maximum length of `2047` characters **after** expansion of the environment variable references. The truncated string assigned to **local** `PATH` of `cmd.exe` can be longer than the string value stored in Windows registry if environment variable references expand to strings which are longer than the environment variable reference strings.

In worst case the **system** `PATH` is truncated twice to a maximum length of `2047` characters, the first time before and the second time after expansion of the environment variable references.

#### Length limitations of user PATH

The **user** `PATH` is ignored completely if the expanded **system** `PATH` concatenated with the expanded **user** `PATH` with an additionally inserted semicolon results in a string value longer than `2047` characters. The maximum length of the **user** `PATH` on Windows XP depends for that reason on current length of expanded **system** `PATH`.

#### Length limitations of Control Panel windows for editing environment variables

A **user** or **system** `PATH` or any other in Windows registry persistent stored environment variable with a string value longer than `4095` characters is not displayed in the **Environment Variables** dialog window. For a user it looks like the environment variable does not exist which has a string value of more than `4095` characters although the environment variable is stored in registry and is perhaps even defined truncated in the **local** environment of running processes. The other **user** and **system** variables are still displayed in the **Environment Variables** window.

The **Edit User Variable** and **Edit System Variable** dialog windows display a **Variable value** with up to `2047` characters. A user can edit an even longer string value and save the string value, but the string value is always truncated to a maximum length of `2047` characters as displayed in edit field of the window. A user cannot append characters or replace existing characters on string value of the environment variable is longer than `2047` characters.

#### Recommendations for PATH lengths

The **system** `PATH` as stored in Windows registry and in its expanded form should be never longer than `2047` characters on Windows XP.

The **user** `PATH` in its expanded form should be short enough to be not ignored on concatenating it with the **system** `PATH`.

Comment: BTW: I plan to run all the black box tests also on Windows 10 and Windows 11 to find out the `PATH` length limitations of the mainly used Windows versions and edit my an answer with appropriate information. Additional information to add to this answer are welcome at any time.